# (PHP) PDO use different querys dependent on set variables

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepare

I want to insert into a database via pdo, but if some variables aren't set I won't write them into the database obviously.

Example:

$name is set

$surname isn't set

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET name = ?");
$query->execute(array($name));
```

Example 2:

$name is set

$surname is set

```
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET name = ?, surname = ?");
$query->execute(array($name, $surname));
```

How would I implement it with only one prepare and execute? Or what is the smartest way to implement it?

Comment: Build a query as a variable.

Comment: Use an if condition and use either one of these queries depending on the if condition evaluation.

Comment: Please read the manual for the `INSERT` syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html Then start again

Comment: *Technically speaking*, you've a missing quote here `("INSERT INTO customer SET name = ?, surname = ?)`

Comment: Try a ternary operator.

Comment: @u_mulder & Charlotte Dunois: So I can do it like $query = $db->prepare($sql); and set $sql via if conditions?

Comment: @RiggsFolly I don't see your problem, this is a valid example insert query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an if condition to check if the variables are set

```
if(isset($name))
{
 if(isset($surname))
 {
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET name = ?, surname = ?");
    $query->execute(array($name, $surname));

 }
 else {

  $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET name = ?");
$query->execute(array($name));
}
}
```

Edit:
You can try this code if you want only a single prepare statement

```
if(isset($name))
 {
     $q="INSERT INTO customer SET name = ?";
    $arr=array($name);
    if(isset($surname))
 {
  $q="INSERT INTO customer SET name = ?, surname = ?";
  $arr[]=$surname;

}

}

$query = $db->prepare($q);
$query->execute($arr);
```

Comment: I only want to write prepare and execute once. Can I do it like $query = $db->prepare($sql); $query->execute(array($set_variables)); and set $sql and $set_variables in the if isset conditions?

Comment: The edit looks almost like the solution I want. I will try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question, you want to insert the value of surname even it it isn't set.

```
$db->exec('INSERT INTO `customer`(`name`,`surname`) VALUES('.$dbh->quote($name).','.$dbh->quote($surname).')');
```

the code will insert the value even if it's empty.

EDIT:

if you want to get a response, use this:

```
if($db->exec('INSERT INTO `customer`(`name`,`surname`) VALUES('.$dbh->quote($name).','.$dbh->quote($surname).')')) {
   echo 'Success';
} else { 
    echo 'fail';
}
```

EDIT 2:

```
    /* if name is not set, insert ONLY surname */
    if(!isset($name)) {
       if($db->exec('INSERT INTO `customer`(`surname`) VALUES('.$db->quote('surname').')')){
          echo 'success';
       } else {
          echo 'fail';
       }
    /* if surname is not set, insert ONLY name */
    } elseif(!isset($surname)) {
       if($db->exec('INSERT INTO `customer`(`name`) VALUES('.$db->quote('name').')')){
          echo 'success';
       } else {
          echo 'fail';
       }
    /* if both are set, insert both */
    } else {
       if($db->exec('INSERT INTO `customer`(`name`,`surname`) VALUES('.$db->quote('name').','.$db->quote('surname').')')){
          echo 'success';
       } else {
          echo 'fail';
       }
    }
```

Comment: I only want to insert the set values so if name is set but surname isn't, only set name. If name and surname is set, insert both. If name isn't set but surname is, only set surname

Comment: @thotho - ok, I've updated my answer, checkout > EDIT 2

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
<?php 
if (isset($name)&&isset($surname)) {
    $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET name = ? , surname = ?");
    $query->execute(array($name, $surname));
}else {
    if (isset($name){
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET name = ? ");
        $query->execute(array($name));
    }else{
        $query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO customer SET surname = ? ");
        $query->execute(array($surname));
    }
}


?>
```